# MySQL MASTER TO MASTER replication working at DB level but not application level using Spring / Hibernate

Tags: mysql, database, database-replication

We are using MySQL with MASTER TO MASTER replication.

It works (i.e. replicates to the other DB) when we enter SQL statements directly using the  MySQL monitor i.e. an INSERT or a DELETE on a table.  This has been tested both ways, i.e. on each DB to see if they both replicate to the other one (and they do).

However, when we use our web application using Spring / Hibernate to persist the data, it is saved correctly to the currently connected DB, but it does not replicate to the other one !  I would not have thought this was possible !

I have looked a the log files I can find:
/var/log/mysqld.log
but cannot see any errors.

How can I investigate this further?
Can I improve the logging to be more verbose?
Is this possible to actually bypass replication somehow?  I didn't think so but I have just run a series of tests to prove this.

Comment: check if replication still working by SHOW SLAVE STATUS;

Comment: Yes - working.  Since I tried using the application - I retried (and again just now) a direct insertion that replicated fine.

Comment: It shows "Waiting for master to send event" on both DBs

Comment: check binary logs for further investigation

Comment: you can bypass replication for some queries by addind set global sql_log_bin=0 for particular session

Comment: I don't want to bypass any queries - how do I check the binary logs?

Comment: there must be file created on both server under data directory by default

Comment: You can read the binlogs with the command line tool or with [SHOW BINLOG EVENTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-binlog-events.html), also `SHOW MASTER STATUS` will help in determining a position to read from.

Comment: Can you post the master setup from your my.cnf or my.ini file

Comment: [mysqld]
    datadir=/var/lib/mysql
    socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
    user=mysql
    # Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted         security risks
    symbolic-links=0

log_bin=/var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
    binlog_do_db=DISPLAY
    server-id=1

    [mysqld_safe]
    log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
    pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is that we had STATEMENT based replication not ROW based replication !

Link below explains about STATEMENT based replication (default and what we are using) and ROW based replication 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-do-db

```
mysql> show variables like 'binlog_format';
+---------------+-----------+
| Variable_name | Value     |
+---------------+-----------+
| binlog_format | STATEMENT |
+---------------+-----------+

mysql> SET GLOBAL binlog_format = 'ROW';

/etc/my.cnf

#Setup binary logging
log_bin=/var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
binlog_do_db=MY_DATABASE
binlog-format=ROW
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that by specifying the database name in the datasource TAG in server.xml for the Liberty WebSphere Appserver - it stopped replication !?

Removed the databaseName attribute and it all works fine !

```
<dataSource id="athlete" jndiName="jdbc/myJNDIName">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="MySqlLib"/>
    **<properties databaseName="mydb"** 
    user="myuser" password="password" serverName="myserver" portNumber="3306"/>
</dataSource>
```

The real cause was to do with STATEMENT versus ROW based binary logging
- we were using statement based logging - have switched to ROW based logging and it now works fine.

If STATEMENT based replication (the default for 5.1.71) is used, it will not replicate to the other database if the assigned database for the session is different to the database being replicated.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-do-db

<< 
Statement-based replication.  Tell the slave SQL thread to restrict replication to statements where the default database (that is, the one selected by USE) is db_name.

> >